# Can we find root volume of an AWS instance in boto3?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I need to find the volume id of root volume of my EC2 instance in boto3

I tried getting volumes by `describe_volumes` but there is no identifier for root volume

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aws ec2 describe-instances` to view attached disks. The volumes will appear in the `BlockDeviceMappings` section:

```
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "AttachTime": "2016-01-24T06:46:06+00:00",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "VolumeId": "vol-686feca2"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `DeviceName` of the volume matches `root_device_name` of instance, then that volume is the root volume.

```py
import boto3
session=boto3.session.Session()
ec2=session.resource('ec2')
instance_iterator = ec2.instances.all()
for instance in instance_iterator:
    print(instance.id)
    for device in instance.block_device_mappings:
        if device['DeviceName']==instance.root_device_name:
            print("The root volume is ", device['Ebs']['VolumeId'])
        else:
            print("The additional ebs volume is", device['Ebs']['VolumeId'])
```

Answer (score 0):

> there is no identifier for root volume

Most likely reason is that the volume is **not attached to any instance**.

Default call to [describe-volumes](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html) returns all volumes. If a volume is attached to an instance, it is reflected in its output. If the volume is not attached, than there is no information  about its `Attachments` and `Device` name on the instance.

To list only attached volumes, you can use `filter`:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes \
    --filters Name=attachment.status,Values=attached
```